# why my @yield() is not showing the content? in Laravel PHP template

Tags: php, laravel, backend, laravel-blade, laravel-8

Hello I'm trying to learn laravel, and I got to the point where I stumbled upon this problem in templating where the content is not showing up when using `@yeild` it only shows the content of the main blade file and does not display the @section in the child

here is my code below, what am I doing wrong? and how could I fix this?

---

**views/layouts/sample1_template.blade.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Layout1</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>HEADER</h1>
    
    @yield('contentx')

    <h1>Footer</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

---

**views/sample1_content.blade.php**

```php
@extends('layouts.sample1_template')

@section('contentx')

<h1> Content body </h1>

@endsection
```

---

**in the web.php**

```php
Route::get('/sampleLayout', function() {
    return view('layouts.sample1_template');
});
```

Comment: can't see your code please update your post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that you are still using `layouts.sample1_template` in your `Route`, when you should be using `sample1_content`.

So, change you `Route` code to:

```php
Route::get('/sampleLayout', function() {
    return view('sample1_content');
});
```

Comment: thanks it worked, it weird me out though why do we render the child view instead of the parent

Comment: That is because you use `@extends`, that way you are saying "Child, use this base layout, but change this on that layout", and the only way to reference the child is to do what I had said in the answer. Always reference the child.

Answer (score -1):

```
@extends('backend.layout.mainlayout')

@section('content')

<h1>Test</h1>

@endsection
```